# Inequality under certain assumptions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Let $s\in(1,2)$, $t>1$, $p>2$ and $t-1>\frac{4}{q}t(s-1)$ where $q\in(0,p-1)$ for $p\geq 2$. Then does the following inequality hold:
$$
(s-1)<c(p)(t^q-s^p)
$$
for some constant $c(p)$ depending on $p$.
In fact it hods when $p=2$. The proof goes as follows:
By the mean value theorem there exists $\eta\in(1,t)$ such that $t^q-1=q\eta^{q-1}(t-1)$. Then
$$
\frac{(s+2)(s-1)}{t-1}\leq\frac{q(s+2)}{4t}\leq\frac{q}{t}\leq\frac{q}{t^{1-q}}\leq q\eta^{q-1}=\frac{t^q-1}{t-1}.$$ Therefore, we have
$$
(s+2)(s-1)\leq t^q-1,
$$
which gives
$$
s-1\leq t^q-s^2.
$$
Hence the proof follows. So $c(p)=1$ here.
Any hint when $p>2$?
I tried in this way:
Since $s\in(1,2)$, the term $s^p-1-(s-1)^p$ is bounded. Now suppose the result does not hold, then by contradiction, there exists $s_0\in(1,2)$ $t_0>1$ satisfying the above conditions such that $s_0^{p}-1-(s_0-1)^p\geq c(p)(t_{0}^q-s_{0}^p)$ for all $c(p)$. If $t_0^q-s_0^p>0$ then we can choose $c(p)$ large enough such that the above inequality become false. Hence the result is true.

But if $t_0^{q_0}-s_0^{p}<0$, then I have no clue. In fact it seems that this has to be positive, since this is the case at least for $p=2$. Here may be the condition $t_0-1>\frac{4t_0}{q_0}(s_0-1)$ and $q_0\in(0,p-1)$ have to be cleverly used to prove the positivity.

By MVT the proof goes as follows: We have arguing as above
$$
(s^{p-1}+2s^{p-2})\frac{s-1}{t-1}\leq\frac{q}{4t}(s^{p-1}+2s^{p-2})\leq c(p)\frac{q}{t}\leq c(p)\frac{t^q-1}{t-1}.
$$
Therefore, we get after multiplying
$$
s^{p-1}-2s^{p-2}+c(p)\leq c(p)t^q-s^p.
$$
Now we choose $c(p)$ large enough such that $c(p)-2s^{p-2}\geq -1$ using that $s\in(1,2)$. Therefore we have
$$
s-1\leq s^{p-1}-1\leq c(p)t^q-s^p.
$$
But we need $c(p)(t^q-s^p)$ in the rhs. We note that in the second argument too we have not used that $q\in(0,p-1)$ only used that $q\in(0,1)$.

Thanks in advance for help.